# a script to duplicate mi currect artboard and resize it please

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, illustrator-scripting

I want to do a action but I think that with a script is better, but I´m not good at it:
I want to duplicate my current artboard and resize this new artboard to 30cmx30cm, and make a mask on it, somebody can help me with this please.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? What do you mean by "make a mask on it"? Perhaps visualize with some screenshots or a gif recording showing you doing what you want the action/script to do.

Comment: I haven try anything because I dont know how to make a script, and by make a mask I meant a cliping mask, thanks